# Adjusting scale of bubbles in BubbleChart with python-pptx

Tags: python, python-pptx, bubble-chart

I'm looking for help scaling the size of bubbles in a python-pptx bubble chart, so I have managed to plot a bubble chart using python-pptx and using the following data:

| Risk | Yield | R-adj | Type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0.10 | 0.15 | 0.015 | Cash |
| 0.40 | 0.50 | 0.025 | Money Market |
| 0.60 | 0.20 | 0.015 | Government |
| 2.20 | 5.30 | 0.065 | HY Bonds |
| 1.20 | 2.20 | 0.050 | IG Bonds |
| 1.45 | 3.50 | 0.053 | Yield-Enhanced |
| 2.20 | 3.50 | 0.044 | Equity Infra |

where 'data' variable below is a pandas.DataFrame object representing the table above

```
from pptx import Presentation
from pptx.chart.data import CategoryChartData, ChartData, BubbleChartData
from pptx.enum.chart import (XL_CHART_TYPE, XL_LEGEND_POSITION, XL_LABEL_POSITION)
from pptx.util import Inches, Pt

prs = Presentation(r'template.pptx')
slide = prs.slides[0]

# Create bubble chart
chart_data = BubbleChartData()
for i, asset in enumerate(asset_type):
    series = chart_data.add_series(asset)
    x, y, z = x_series[i], y_series[i], z_series[i]
    series.add_data_point(x,y,z*0.5) # changing z value doesn't change the size of the bubbles

# x, y, cx, cy = Inches(10.8), Inches(4.0), Inches(0.4), Inches(2.4)
x, y, cx, cy = Inches(0.5), Inches(2), Inches(10.8), Inches(4.3)
chart = slide.shapes.add_chart(XL_CHART_TYPE.BUBBLE, x, y, cx, cy, chart_data).chart

# Config legend
chart.has_legend = True
chart.legend.position = XL_LEGEND_POSITION.BOTTOM
chart.legend.include_in_layout = False
```

what I have done is trying to adjust the size of 'z', the size variable, however it seems that changing this value doesn't change the size of the bubbles as it seems that the size of bubbles are proportionate to the plot area, where the largest bubble is x% of the area of the plot, does anybody know how I could adjust the scale of the bubble?

And also include data label on the bubbles, rather than having a legend?

Thanks, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What happens if you change z to a much larger value like 120? I suspect there isn't a direct way to change this using python-pptx. As pptx is XML, try printing out the XML and paste the relevant snippet in your question. Look for '<c:bubbleSize>' . One solution might be to change a 'real' powerpoint slide to match your requirements, examine the XML and then alter the XML manually in your code.